# Is there a Pause button? Where is it?

Tags: chop-chop-ninja

Is there a pause button in Chop Chop Ninja HD? This seems silly, but I can't seem to bring it up if one exists.

Comment: OK. if you don't touch the screen for a couple of seconds, a pause button pops up.

Comment: You could answer your own question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't touch the screen for a few seconds, a pause button pops up.

Comment: feels weird answering a question from 10 years ago, but I'm just bringing the comment answer into the correct place

Comment: That was a terrible UX decision  nice to see some closure after a decade lol